# How can I mail a page in Confluence with showing all recipients to every recipient?

Tags: email, share, confluence

I got a confluence 3.5 installation (but I am fine too, if you tell me there is such an option in 4.2). There is a share button that let you email a page to a bunch of recipients. Sadly all recipients are entered as BCC (or the email task is executed one time for every recipient). Problem: I want to let the recipients know to whom the page has been shared too.

I cannot believe that I could not find anyhting about that topic (just that description: http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONF35/E-mailing+a+Page). So, if this is a silly question for you confluence cracks out there, I am sorry, but happy, if you leave me a hint.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, this was added in Confluence 4.2 and it's really handy!

Now the email you get shows an 'Also shared with' section that has the name and avatar of everyone else.